# Does 60kg of fusion fuel produce as much energy as 400 kilotonnes of coal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass-energy, estimation, fusion

Several people, including [Fusion for Energy](http://fusionforenergy.europa.eu/understandingfusion/merits.aspx) have posted this infographic:

[image: Graphic comparing the amount of oil, coal, or "fusion" fuel to power a city]

> To meet the energy needs of a **city of 1 million people** one would need:
>
> Either
>   **250,000** tonnes of **oil**
>   Or
>   **400,000** tonnes of **coal**
>   Or
>   **60** kg of **fusion fuel**

Ignoring the fact that the info-graphic doesn't include for how long, What I'm asking here is about the rough equality of two energies?

I assume by fusion fuel they mean deuterium/tritium.

Is 60kg of fusion fuel energy equivalent to 400,000,000kg of coal?

Comment: May be a better suit to physics but I'm skeptical so I posted it here

Comment: Heck, one ounce of coal could power a city of a million people ... for a few nanoseconds.

Comment: What does this graphic even mean?   **For how long** ?  So silly.....

Comment: The initial part of the infographic is indeed vague, however the question as asked here is about the rough equality of two energies, which is a very valid question.

Comment: @Fattie The exact value of time span is irrelevant. It's enough to assume it's same for all 3 cases.

Comment: The energy density is certainly there, but accessing it to make electricity is difficult.

Comment: @EL_DON Again, the loses are irrelevant, as long as they're roughly same. And because all that we can do is to heat up a boiler, they are same.

Comment: @Agent_L If you've found a way to heat up a boiler using nuclear fusion that produces net positive energy, let alone with a similar efficiency to coal, you should probably publish it. Unfortunately, you'd be a bit late for this year's Nobel prize in physics, but you'd be certain to win next year's. On second thought, forget the Nobel. _Patent_ it and you'll be able to hire Bill Gates to shine your shoes.

Comment: I will point out that (in addition to the minor detail of achieving controlled fusion) there are three factors that enter in to the overall "efficiency" of an energy-production scheme:  1) The costs (in money and environmental impacts) of extracting the resource.  (This includes fusion, as I'm guessing that extracting the isotopes isn't cheap.)  2) The efficiency of the "burning" process.  3) The energy lost in converting heat into electricity.  Presumably #3 would be about equal for all fuels, but the others could vary greatly.

Comment: @Agent_L The efficiency of the steam turbine at the end is probably the same, but there's a lot more to it than that. Coal needs to be mined, transported, and then shoveled (not literally anymore) into the furnace. Fusion needs to demonstrate solutions to challenges in plasma physics (which can probably be overcome with enough research) and the tritium breeding fuel cycle. Hopefully, the ITER project will show that the major problems can be solved and a power plant is viable.

Comment: This question is really just **clickbait**.  It reads "Could...." for a reason.  The infographic in question is totally incoherent propaganda, and the "Could..." nature of the headline perfectly plays in to that.

Comment: I mean - why doesn't the infographic and this question add yet another line at the end!  **"or! 30kg of coal used as a matter-anti-matter reactor!"**  The whole thing is beyond silly.

Comment: @Fattie hope that's better for you mate

Comment: @Fattie Energy generation by nuclear fusion is well within the domain of "things we haven't done, but we understand the physics well enough to know that they can be done". A matter-antimatter reactor, on the other hand, requires antimatter fuel. Coal is not antimatter, so throwing 30 kg of coal into a matter-antimatter reactor gives you zero energy.

Comment: Hi @Wouter - nobody is a bigger fan of "fusion" than me.  **But then, I'm a big fan of a mission to alpha centauri**.  Your comment that we "understand the physics" of fusion ... we completely understand the physics of travel to the next star.  Note that as of today **a mission to alpha centauri would be tremendously easier, and far cheaper, than achieving fusion power**.  Note too that we completely, totally, understand anti-matter physics and how it would be used to produce power.  The sort of time lines for ITER is that around "2040" (wtf?!) they are "thinking of having some demonstration."

Comment: Maybe someone could compare a fusion explosion with a coal-dust explosion.

Comment: @Albert Also note that with **fission** — that is to say present day nuclear power — the numbers are equally staggering. 2 kg of uranium will hold you with electricity for your **entire life**. [Obligatory xkcd: **log-scale**](https://xkcd.com/1162/)

Comment: "Someday, after mastering the winds, the waves, the tides and gravity, we shall harness for God the energies of love, and then, for a second time in the history of the world, man will have discovered fire."
-- Teilhard de Chardin

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. See for example [this table of energy densities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density).

Let's take 30 MJ/kg for coal (the middle of the range in the table), then 400,000 tonnes of coal [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(400000+t)*(30MJ%2Fkg)) 1.2*10<sup>16</sup> Joule.

Assuming they're talking about deuterium-tritium fusion ([which is the easiest form of nuclear fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion#/media/File:Fusion_rxnrate.svg)), we have 340,000,000 MJ/kg, and the 60 kg [gives us](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(60kg)*(340000000+MJ%2Fkg)) 2.04*10<sup>16</sup> Joule.

Of course, both the coal and the (as-of-yet hypothetical) fusion plant will have inefficiencies that prevent us from extracting 100% of this energy.

The 340,000,000 MJ/kg number can be calculated from the energy released in a single deuterium-tritium reaction, see for example [here](https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/research/cfsa/people/pastmembers/peeters/teaching/lecture1.ppt).

Comment: I think you should make it clear that we have no idea how to use this energy, except in order to destroy the city.

Comment: @ugoren Could you elaborate on that a bit?  While efficiency recovering-and-using the heat's an engineering design problem, it doesn't seem like recovering-and-using the energy in a less-than-optimized way should be too difficult.

Comment: The basic problem is that we need another form of energy to [spark the fusion reaction](http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/energy/a8914/why-dont-we-have-fusion-power-15480435/), but it takes more energy to start the reaction than we get back from it.  This works in a fusion bomb because we wrap it inside a fission bomb.  It's possible that a bigger fusion plant would work, but we won't actually know until we try it.

Comment: @ugoren Cold fusion's a different topic.  Efficiently recovering energy from a fusion reaction as currently imagined requires working at high temperatures, whereas cold fusion's a hypothetical fusion process that could happen far closer to room temperature, avoiding the design problem.  While it'd have been nice if discovered, realistically speaking the first fusion reactors are unlikely to be cold fusion reactors, unless some major new discovery happens in the near-future.  Existing cold-fusion literature is widely regarded as discredited.

Comment: @ugoren Here in Europe, [we’re working towards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITER) using the energy to power cities instead of destroying them.

Comment: @Brythan That article sums it up nicely:  **"_"For $20 billion in cash," [Steve Cowley, director of the Culham Centre for Fusion Energy] says, "I could build you a working reactor. It would be big, and maybe not very reliable, but 25 years ago we didn't even know if we'd be able to make fusion work. Now, the only question is whether we'll be able to make it affordable."_"**

Comment: @Nat Because his working reactor is still very theoretical and hasn't been proven even on a small scale, I think he is just making things up. Theoretical usages of things aren't up to Skeptics standards until they become real.

Comment: Oh, we know how to trigger fusion, we just can't break even on it yet, partly because we're doing one shot fusion reactions rather than sustained fusion.  Part of the work being done is scaling up.  The real issue is that fusion only works in a star because of gravity, to replicate outside of a star requires either a lot more magnetic confinement (JET style) or a ridiculous amount of extra initiation energy (NIF style).

Comment: OTOH, fission reactors are comparatively simple.

Comment: @jamesqf - But cleaning up after them isn't.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The whole developed world has been working towards that since at least the 1950s. The problem is that none of us have demonstrated a successful prototype yet. It turns out that it's much easier to use fusion to destroy cities than to power them.

Comment: This would have to be one of the **worst answers on this site**.  The whole point of this bizarre scam infographic is that (obviously, at a grade-school level) they are using a specific technical issue "specific energy" in an utterly nonsensical way to make a vaguely coherent-sounding headline.  It's **absolutely astounding** that on a skeptic's site, this infographic and clickbait question ("Could ...?") wasn't simply met with a chorus of trivial dismissals.

Comment: Indeed, the **wildest dream**, as it were, of the clown that created the infographic, would be, that people get caught up in a technical discussion of  "specific energy" arcana, utterly ignoring the absurdity of the infographic.  So silly.

Comment: @Fattie This is on Physics SE now, and has been for longer than it was on Skeptics SE.  Nothing in this answer isn't true.  If we were extracting all the energy from fissionable material instead of coal; it would be more efficient per unit mass.  No one here is trying to make a political statement about energy sources.  Obviously a graphic from "Fusion for Energy" is biased and only compares two heavy consumption forms of power generation.  Even for skeptics, it's still true that fusion would produce that much compared to coal.  The graphic doesn't say we _can_ currently do that.

Comment: "it's still true that fusion would produce that much compared to coal"  But what are you talking about, friend?  What process?  Can you even state - for example - what theoretical efficiencies you have in mind?  (Or - whatever?)

Comment: @Fattie They are talking about the theoretical energy content we can extract from each method.  You can calculate the theoretical energy released by burning coal or oil.  You can also calculate the theoretical energy released from various fusion processes.  None of those numbers account for how the energy is extracted and the relevant inefficiencies.  They are looking at theoretical energy densities.  Clearly this infographic isn't a source of exact information.  It's comparing the relative energy density of these processes.  The numbers seem to come from a logical place.

Comment: What you are saying is *absolutely incorrect*.  The infographic literally begins with the English words **"To meet the energy needs of a city...."**  *It literally could not be more misleading.* It is a superb example of complete, total, claptrap - of absolute deception.

Comment: @Fattie It says "To meet the energy needs of a city, one would need..." It's _unclear_, sure.  That part is absolutely true.  I don't agree that's it's misleading though.  It doesn't specify a timeframe for those energy needs, but if you assume a consistent timeframe (and the ability to get energy from fusion) this provides an estimate of relative amounts of fuel needed.  It definitely could be more misleading.  It could also be more clear.  The numbers that they provide can be approximately verified though.

Comment: *"this provides an estimate of relative amounts of fuel needed"*  it absolutely does not, in any way at all - even vaguely.  They are using a technical issue, "specific energy", in an utterly nonsensical way.  Again: it literally and simply **does not** provide an estimate of the relative amounts of fuel needed.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR**:  In theory, yes.  In practice, with currently built technology, no.

#### Theory

As already [posted](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/39725/30596) the fusion reaction produces more energy from the 60 kg of deuterium/tritium mix than burning 400,000,000 kg of coal does.  This comparison is probably the basis for the claim.

#### Practice

The problem comes in two parts.  First, to utilize that power, we have to convert it from a fusion reaction to something else, e.g. electricity.  We have a basic plan for that.  As we do with coal, we'll create heat and then use the heat to power a steam turbine.  Given heat, the problem is basically the same.

The greater problem is that a fusion reaction requires a lot of energy to start and maintain.  In the [sun](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph241/olson1/), part of that energy comes in the form of heat that is a side effect of the fusion reactions already occurring.  Another part of that energy comes from gravity.  Because the sun is so huge, it pulls things together so much that they fuse.  On the Earth, we couldn't do that.  So instead, we use magnets to push things together and simulate what gravity does in the sun.

Unfortunately, the Tokamak version is not that efficient.  In fact, the most efficient it has ever been is [65%](http://www.physicscentral.com/explore/action/fusion.cfm) of the energy needed to keep it going.  So we might burn 60 kg of fusion fuel, but it would take something like 250 kilotons of coal to do it.  And that just gets us to parity.  I.e. zero output.  And that takes the 65% number as gospel.  But some [dispute it](http://news.newenergytimes.net/2017/10/06/the-iter-power-amplification-myth/), arguing that the real efficiency was more like 2% or even 1%.

It's possible that a larger version would be able to produce a net output once started.  [Popular Science](http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/energy/a8914/why-dont-we-have-fusion-power-15480435/) quotes Steve Cowley, director of the Culham Centre for Fusion Energy:

> "For $20 billion in cash," he says, "I could build you a working reactor. It would be big, and maybe not very reliable, but 25 years ago we didn't even know if we'd be able to make fusion work. Now, the only question is whether we'll be able to make it affordable."

And of course, even if we built a [$22 billion](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/27/science/fusion-power-plant-iter-france.html) [fusion reactor](https://www.iter.org/proj/inafewlines), we don't know what the efficiency would be.  We can sort of guess, but we don't actually know.  That's part of the point behind building the prototype:  to find out how it performs in reality rather than in theoretical models.  Perhaps it will produce more energy than is put into it.  Or perhaps we will discover that [practical fusion is still at least 30 years away](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/crux/2016/03/23/nuclear-fusion-reactor-research/).

Answer (score 3):

This depends entirely on what you mean by "energy equivalent." If you're talking about the amount of the fuel that would be needed *to provide a given amount of electrical power with current technology*, then the answer is **no, they are not equivalent.** Given the infographic's discussion of "powering a city," it is suggesting this interpretation, as this is the only meaningful interpretation for how a city might be powered.

On the other hand, if you're merely asking about how much energy we can get out of the fuel if we don't care about things like, say, destroying the city in which the reaction takes place or getting any useful electrical power from the reaction, the amount of energy is actually underestimated a bit for the fusion, though the order of magnitude is accurate. So, if you're more concerned with *destroying* a city than with powering it, fusion is a great choice.

---

#### Fusion for Electrical Power

Theoretically speaking, fusion power production would be great. There's lots of fuel available, the energy density is greater than even nuclear fission, and it doesn't produce as much radioactive waste. Unfortunately, however, as of 2017, despite about 6-7 decades of research, [no one has yet been able to build a nuclear fusion reactor that produces positive net energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_power).

The reason for this is that fusion reactions generally require very large amounts of input energy both to create the plasma stream and to contain it. [Lots of various designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_power#Approaches) have been proposed and/or tried in order to increase the ratio of produced power to input power, but, to date, none have reached a ratio of 1 or more, thus, all have produced negative net energy. Obviously, this is not very helpful when attempting to power a city. The infographic is being quite misleading by leaving out this little detail.

Of course, this is not to suggest that further research will not eventually create a fusion reactor that produces positive net energy. It's entirely possible (and, IMO, likely) that we'll eventually have a working design. But we've currently been unable to demonstrate a working prototype, so it's not a matter of just building a bunch of fusion plants today.

---

#### Fuel Specific Energy

The [Specific Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_energy) of a fuel is its ratio of stored energy to mass, without any regard to how much external energy may be required to actually do something productive with the fuel.

[Wikipedia lists the specific energies for many fuels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#Energy_densities_of_common_energy_storage_materials) in megajoules (MJ) of energy per kilogram (kg) of fuel mass:

- Deuterium-Tritium: 340,000,000 MJ/kg
- Coal: 24-35 MJ/kg
- Diesel fuel: 48 MJ/kg
- Gasoline: 46.4 MJ/kg

Using these numbers, we find that 60 kg of Deuterium-Tritium fuel stores the same amount of potential energy as (340,000,000 / 48) * 60 = 425,000,000 kg = 425,000 metric tonnes of Diesel.

For coal (being generous and assuming 35 MJ/kg for the coal,) the calculation is (340,000,000 / 35) * 60 = approximately 580,000,000 kg = approximately 580,000 metric tons of coal.

For gasoline, it's (340,000,000 / 46.4) * 60 = approximately 440,000,000 kg or 440,000 metric tons of gasoline.

The massive specific energy of fusion fuels is what allows us to construct fusion-based bombs. In the case of a bomb controlling and containing the reaction aren't primary concerns, since the whole point is to destroy everything nearby anyway in most cases. However, we unfortunately can't ignore those things when building a power plant.

---

**tl;dr**  The infographic is more or less correct about the ratio of specific energies, but is incorrect in suggesting that we could use those amounts of fuel to actually provide electrical power to an equivalent market with present-day technology.

Comment: The only worthwhile answer here.  Note however that this sentence: *"The infographic is more or less correct about the ratio of specific energies, but is incorrect in suggesting that we could use those amounts of fuel to actually provide electrical power to an equivalent market with present-day technology."* wildly understates the total incoherence, the completely blatant scam aspect, of the infographic in question.  I'd phrase it more like....

Comment: ***"The infographic uses the technical concept 'specific energy' (which is all-but utterly irrelevant to the issues at hand) as clickbait to make a political point."*** Note too that like all good propaganda, the person who typed it out lacks even **basic, arithmetic-level skills** in the topic at hand.  ("Energy needs" is utterly irrelevant unless you give a time/rate.)  Note too that as a political matter, I am entirely, 10000% on the side of "Fusion for Energy" political action group - I would literally give them money to support them! But the infographic is ... hilarious.  Totally risible.

Comment: @Fattie oh relax mate, you're acting like my objective here is some big conspiracy. I'm just asking an honest question to get a reasonable answer. Which I did

Comment: @Fattie I'm not sure why you're going on crusades in these comments...  You're saying it's nonsense because the "energy needs" don't give a timeframe for their power.  The thing is, they don't need to really specify the timeframe that this energy is used.  Over the period of time you would need to burn 400,000 tonnes of coal, there is theoretically the same power in 60 kg of fusion fuel.  You don't need a time/rate at all.  They would use equivalent energy per hour/day/month/year regardless.

Comment: @Fattie You're implying that this infographic is saying "We should get all our energy from fusion now!" when what it suggests to me is "We need to research into fusion more as a fuel source".

Comment: @JMac The energy use would be equivalent regardless of source, but comparing just the specific energies isn't especially meaningful as it relates to power production unless you have some way to actually convert said energy to electrical power. With current technology, no amount of fusion fuel would produce an equivalent amount of electrical power to 400,000 tonnes of coal because we don't have a working way to produce net positive electrical power from fusion in the first place.

Comment: @JMac I'm all for nuclear fusion power, but it looks like that site is just making stuff up. They say, for example, "A 1,000 MW electric fusion power plant would consume around 100 kg of deuterium and three tonnes of natural lithium in a year whilst generating 7 billion kW-hr. The problem is that those numbers are pure fantasy with present technology. Right now, fusing 100 kg of deuterium would produce a rather dramatically negative amount of output energy, unless said deuterium is in a bomb.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the efficiency of the nuclear reactor in question, as well as the efficiency of the method used to extract said energy. Since the only nuclear fusion reactor that produces more energy that it takes in that we currently have access to is the Sun, and the Earth as a whole only receives 1 x 10^-9 of the Sun's radiated energy according to a page hosted by the University of Illinois (http://extension.illinois.edu/world/energy.cfm), and since according to Wikipedia, the Sun is currently fusing 620 million tons of hydrogen in its core each second, that means that about the energy of about 562 kilograms of fuel reaches the Earth each second (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion).

Since the Earth receives about 174 petawatts of Solar energy each second according to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_energy), we can work out that the energy per kilogram of the Sun's fuel is 3.058 x 10^8 J/kg. So, multiply that by 60 to get the energy in 60 kg of nuclear fuel. However, since we only receive one billionth of that energy, we're only getting .3058 J/kg. Multiply that by 60 kg, and you get 18.35 J. That's not very much; approximately enough to life a bag of 18 apples one meter, and that's without taking the inefficiencies involved in converting solar energy into something useful.

Comment: Umm, one observation. Most of that "174 petawatts" of Our Main Fusion Powerplant are *already* used to power all the cities *today*. If you only used coal, no way you could afford to heat the air in the whole city to nice ~290 kelvins or to fuel the ecosystem via photosynthesis (food&oxygen for inhabitants).

Comment: @kubanczyk - Oh, but the Sun is just a big lump of burning coal.  Any other explanation is just science fiction voodoo.

Answer (score 0):

Fusion produces a net output of 630 Terajoules per Kilogram (1kg + 1 Kg)
so 60 kg is 37.8 Petajoules; With 3.6 million joules in a kilowatt hour that's 10.5 Billion kwh or 10.5 million Megawatt hours, the equivalent of 437,500 Megawatts of daily generation capacity. Global electric consumption in 2018 was 23.4 Trillion Kwh / 365 days a year = 64 billion Kwh a day. So it would take 366 kg a day